# Javascript Array of Object Code

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to create an Array of Objects as given below

```
var selection_json_str=[
    {
        "idx":0,
        "fieldname":"%Key0",
        "fieldvalue": [
            "05-5003",
            "05-5005",
            "06-6007",
            "06-6009"]
     },
     {
         "idx":1,
         "fieldname":"%Key1",
         "fieldvalue": [
             "5003",
             "5005",
             "6007",
             "6009"]
     },
     {
         "idx":2,
         "fieldname":"%Key2",
         "fieldvalue":[
             "1",
             "1"]
     }
]

var noCols = _this.Data.HeaderRows[0].length;
var selection_json_str = {}
for (var c = 0; c < noCols; c++) {
    var t = [];
    var a = []
    for (var r = 0; r < _this.Data.Rows.length; r++) {
        a.push(_this.Data.Rows[r][c].text);
    }
    //ConsoleInfo(a);
    //ConsoleInfo(GetUnique(a)); Get Unique Key from the list
    selection_json_str[c] = {
        idx: c,
        fieldname: _this.Data.HeaderRows[0][c].text,
        fieldvalue:GetUnique(a)
    };
}
```

I have a code which I have to change to get the above output , can any one help me out here . I need to have array of objects within selection_json_str . Can any help me out ?

Comment: `var selection_json_str = []` might work

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var selection_json_str = new Array();
for (var c = 0; c < noCols; c++) {
    var t = [];
    var a = []
    for (var r = 0; r < _this.Data.Rows.length; r++) {
        a.push(_this.Data.Rows[r][c].text);
    }
    //ConsoleInfo(a);
    //ConsoleInfo(GetUnique(a)); Get Unique Key from the list
    selection_json_str.push({
        idx: c,
        fieldname: _this.Data.HeaderRows[0][c].text,
        fieldvalue:GetUnique(a)
    });
}
```

[Explanation](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp)

### A bit extra explanation:

I've changed selection_json_str to new Array() that we will know what kind of data will be there. And when I add a new element I just call selection_json_str.push(element). It's not necessary to call push, but I prefer to do it when I'm adding something to array. It gives a better understanding of code. (IMHO)
After our loop is done we'll have array of objects in selection_json_str

Comment: `push` is not necessary here, the bracket notation used in OP code is fine too. Also it would be better to explain what changes you've made, instead of copy pasting a sample of code.

Comment: Is it better now? I know that push is not necessary, but I prefer to use it when I'm adding new element to array because it was made for it and it returns the length of array, so I save one line of code :)